# Getting rid of nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, optimization

I am a complete novice to coding and quite stuck at getting rid of nested for loops.

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for sublink in links:
        if A[i, sublink[0]] >= 1:
            vec = np.array(A[i]).tolist()
            vec[sublink[0]] -= 1
            vec[sublink[1]] += 1
            yield vec
```

Say I have links as `links = [[0,1],[1,2],[1,0],[2,1]]` and `A=[3,0,0,2,1,0,1,2,0]` I want to loop over the flatten NumPy array A in a way that the loop initially runs over first three elements of the A and executes whatever inside the for loop block. Then the loop runs over the second three elements segment of the flatten A and so on.

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in making the nested loop flat and that is your only goal you can use Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

nplist = np.array(list_)

#flatten
nplist = np.ndarray.flatten(nplist)

list_ = list(nplist)
```

Comment: I know this, the problem is that let's say you have a list that contains 9 elements. I want to loop over the list in a way that initially the loop runs over the first three items in the list and modify some elements thereof. Then the loop needs to run over the second three items and modify some elements thereof etc.